# Permissions with Samba Share

Tags: permissions, samba, ownership

I created a samba share with anonymous access. 
I changed the permissions/ownership of all files and folder to root. I can read, write and delete to the share.

now I installed a torrent program (deluge). I set the download dir to the share (its local). Whenever deluge downloads a file it creates with its own user "deluge".

I cant read, but can't delete the file from the share because I dont have the permission. What do i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

you have many solutions to this case

1. add your user as a member of the group deluge
2. change ownership of created files by deluge
3. change permissions of the newly created files

---

> Add your user as a member of the group deluge

```
sudo usermod group-name user-name
```

---

> change ownership of created files by deluge

```
sudo chown username:username /path-to-files-created-by-deluge
```

---

> change permissions of the newly created files

```
sudo chmod 777 /path-to-files-created-by-deluge
```